# How to act when a user posts the same question multiple times by wording differently?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, behavior

A user asked a question on SO, to w. I have done my best to answer this question. The user accepted the answer but did not ask any further questions.

#### Original question from a user:

[How should I perform this file/ folder distribution task; SSIS or command script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14961064/how-should-i-perform-this-file-folder-distribution-task-ssis-or-command-script)

When a user accepts the answer, I usually check their profile to see if they have any other unanswered questions of interest that I could possibly answer. That's when I realized what this user was doing.

#### Questions created from original question's answer:

Now, the OP has posted three different questions that is no different than the original question.

[Folder and file operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14976547/folder-and-file-operations)

[How to copy/replace a file into a folder in VB.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14978894/vb-how-to-copy-replace-a-file-into-a-folder)

[VB.NET Iteration and folder operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14980205/vb-net-iteration-and-folder-operations)

#### What should I do when I come across such behavior?

I feel that I might have made a mistake by answering the user's question. My intention was to make it useful to others, the code sections explain what it exactly does, and not just OP but I guess it did not have the right effect on OP. I feel that all the questions listed above look same in one way or the other.I feel that the user is very lazy to put any further efforts into the input provided by others. I don't like to encourage such behavior.

- I could vote to close these questions as duplicate of the original question. In my opinion, I think that is the appropriate action. Am I correct or are these valid questions in their own right?
- I usually watch only questions on [ssis](/questions/tagged/ssis). The user originally posted the question under [ssis](/questions/tagged/ssis) but further questions were posted under [vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net). How to catch this kind of behavior that does not add much value to community?
- Should I flag these questions for moderator's attention, I do not want to burden moderator's unnecessarily by raising unwanted flags or should I leave a comment stating that it is not an appropriate behavior to post repeated questions?

#### Update:

Vote to close under [ssis](/questions/tagged/ssis) rarely attracts more votes to close. I usually end up flagging it for moderator's attention so they could close those questions. I don't know about [vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net).

Answer (score 4):

If you were a low rep user, flag. But you aren't. You have all the powers of a 10k user. So use them! Close his other questions as duplicates. Cast delete votes if they're really that bad. And if he really gets out of hand, then flag. But if you can handle the situation with your level of privileges, do! Gather one or two more 10k mods here on meta (I'd help if I was one!) and do a bit of cleanup.

Note: If this keeps happening no matter what you do, *then* start flagging.

Comment: @Siva: Raise a problem here. If there's a problem, people will come and help you close. I'd help, but I've got to go.

Comment: I see this type of question posted numerous times also, how do you see it as a problem? Ignoring is an option as well.

Comment: @user24015: Yes, but that give the impression that it's OK. We need to show them that it isn't, and at least use our close votes to show good users that it's not OK to feed the help vampires.

Comment: Right, i get that part but its kind of a waste of time when you could be answering questions. Build a program with some code that eliminates redundant questions. Ask it to evaluate the words and if there's a match, send to a process that keeps it from posting.